# ESXi 6.7 VMWare Backup to External USB Drive

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi

Using VMWare ESXi 6.7.0 with Essentials licensing, I would like to backup my VMs to a plugged External HD. Previously we did it with Veeam because we were using a Windows Server, but now with their Hypervisor we couldn't find some way to do it.

What I've already seen:

**Veeam** - Couldn't find an apropriate solution for what we need, is it possible to install it or use remotely without paid agent solutions?

**OVF Export** - From what I did understand by reading this feature would use the network to export the VM. That´s not exactly what I'm looking for (if it's this)

**ghettoVCB.sh** - I'm not sure if this one works with this version, from what I did read it works with version 5 and 4.

Is there any other way to achieve this using free alternatives to communicate with ESXi 6.7?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Veeam - Couldn't find an apropriate solution for what we need, is it possible to install it or use remotely without paid agent solutions?` - What do you mean by that? You buy Veeam for the host server, based on CPU sockets. What's this agent you're referring to?

Comment: This one, is it necessary to have an agent to run and manage my backups? https://www.veeam.com/linux-cloud-server-backup-agent.html

Comment: No. You don't need that.

Comment: So for Veeam on Linux do I download an iso from the website and install it? Do I have to format the External USB Drive on some specific way so it gets recognized?

Answer (score 2):

What's with the file system on the external USB?

If you have any Windows-based VMs (or you can create one), you can pass-through external USB to the Windows VM, Install Veeam and set external USB device as a backup repository for Veeam Backups.

But be sure, that Veeam update 3a must be installed to make a backup from ESXi 6.7

Comment: Nice, I'll do those tests and report back ok?